# Convergence of a series of integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

#### Definition of problem

I would like to find the large $N$ behaviour of a summation series and specifically the conditions under which it converges. I have found one condition, but I think it might be possible to do better, so any pointers would be appreciated. The series is of real values defined by
$$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} x\, s_n(x)$$
where $s_0 = \delta(x)$ and for higher values of $i$
$$s_{n+1}(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \frac{c}{|x|} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} z \, s_n(z)p(x-z) &  &|x|>0, \\
0 &  &x=0
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $c>0$ and the function $p$ is given by
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_i p_i \left( \delta(x-x_i) + \delta(x+x_i) \right)
$$
with $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and a finite set of points $x_i$.

#### Progress so far

To understand the behaviour of the sequence, it is noted that the support of  the functions $s_n(x)$ is made up of the non-zero points $x = \sum_i n_i x_i$ for $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus for $x_i/x_j \in \mathbb{Q} \,\,\forall x_i, x_j$ there is a finite lower bound for $|x|$ given by $x_\mathrm{min}$.

$$ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle  \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} x \,\,s_n(x) &=&  \displaystyle \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} x \frac{c}{|x|} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} z \, s_{n-1}(z)p(x-z) \\
 & \leq & \displaystyle   \frac{c}{x_\mathrm{min}} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} x \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} z \, s_{n-1}(z)p(x-z)
\\
& = & \displaystyle \frac{c}{x_\mathrm{min}} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathrm{d} x \,\,s_{n-1}(x)  \\
& \leq & \displaystyle  \left( \frac{c}{x_\mathrm{min}} \right)^n
\end{array}
$$
Which suggests that the series $S$ converges if $c < x_\mathrm{min}$.
Unfortunately this is the case I have managed to make progress with. Numerical attempts suggest that for if $ \exists x_i, x_j$ such that $x_i/x_j \notin \mathbb{Q}$ the $n$th term of $S$ scales as something more like $\sim n^n$, which would preclude convergence. However of greater interest to me would be a tighter bound.